Dynamically accessing a json Object leads to Microsoft.CSharp.Runtime.RuntimeBinderException
This is what my C# code looks like:
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

var username = "[REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW]";
var token = "[REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW]";
var url = "https://[REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW].atlassian.net//rest/api/2/search?jql=ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC&maxResults=1&startAt=0";

var mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, token);
var byteCredentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
var encodedCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

    var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    dynamic jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(result);

    Console.WriteLine(jsonObject["issues"]);
}

With this code I make an API call to get the last updated issue.
This is what I get as response:
{
  "expand": "names,schema",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 1,
  "total": 19052,
  "issues": [
    { ... }
}

If I try to acess f.e. 'issues', I get this issue:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Nachricht = The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
Source = <The exception source cannot be evaluated.> 
Stack monitoring: <The exception stack monitoring cannot be evaluated.> 

I tried accessing 'issues' using jsonObject["issues"] like they said in this tutorial:
// JSON text for deserialization
string json = "{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Age\":30}";

// Deserialize the JSON text into a dynamic object
dynamic jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

// Access the properties of the dynamic object
string name = jsonObject["Name"];
int age = jsonObject["Age"];

// Output the retrieved data
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
Console.WriteLine("Alter: " + age);

I was expecting it to show the issue, so that I then can get more things like title, author etc.

System.Text.Json does not support deserializing to dynamic because it's DOM types JsonNode and JsonElement do not implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.  See this answer to Read value from dynamic property from json payload.

You will need to either deserialize to JsonNode (preferred) or JsonElement and work with them using their explicit APIs, or deserialize to ExpandoObject.  To deserialize a JSON hierarchy to an ExpandoObject hierarchy you can use ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter from this answer to C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>.  Does that answer your question?
